# PSQL: How to compare record to previous record (2 tables)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, compare

I have two tables:

01_System_Log

```
request_date   request_id
2022-01-01     1
2022-01-10     2
2022-01-20     3
```

Records

```
firm    name    city  request_id

firm_a  John    NY              1
firm_b  Will    LA              1
firm_c  Andy    SF              1
firm_c  Marga   CH              1

firm_a  John    NY              2
firm_b  Will    LA              2
firm_b  Nancy   LA              2
firm_c  Andy    SF              2
firm_c  Marga   CH              2

firm_a  John    NY              3
firm_b  Will    CH              3
firm_b  Nancy   LA              3
firm_c  Andy    SF              3
firm_c  Marga   SF              3 
firm_c  Joe     SF              3
```

I need to create a view, where the records of the last request id (3) are compared with the previous (2). So far I made a view, where the most actual records are shown.

```
SELECT DISTINCT main.firm,
    main.name,
    main.city,
    sys_log.request_id,
FROM "Records" main
INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT sys.request_date,
           sys.request_id
    FROM "01_System_Log" sys
    ORDER BY sys.request_id DESC
    LIMIT 1 ) sys_log ON sys_log.request_id = main.request_id
WHERE  main.request_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY main.firm;
```

I am not sure how to proceed, while in all compare examples, which I have found, only one table was used.

My ideal result is:

```
firm   name_    city  request_id  firm_n name_n  city_n  request_id_n

firm_a  John     NY    2          firm_a  John     NY    3
firm_b  Will     LA    2          firm_b  Will     CH    3
firm_b  Nancy    LA    2          firm_b  Nancy    LA    3
firm_c  Andy     SF    2          firm_c  Andy     SF    3
firm_c  Marga    CH    2          firm_c  Marga    SF    3 
                                  firm_c  Joe      SF    3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information is all coming from one table `"Records"` so you just need to include that table twice in your query, using appropriate aliases, once to get the records with the highest `request_id` and once for the `request_id` which is lower than the highest. Finally you need to find what the highest `request_id` is, which you can do with a CTE on the `"01_System_Log"` table.

The CTE is straightforward:

```
WITH highest AS (
    SELECT request_id AS id
    FROM "01_System_Log"
    ORDER BY request_date DESC LIMIT 1
)
```

The records that use the highest `request_id` are also easily found:

```
SELECT firm, name, city, request_id
FROM "Records"
JOIN highest ON "Records".request_id = highest.id
```

To get the records with the second highest `request_id` for each combination of firm and name you need to use a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS):

```
SELECT DISTINCT firm, name, 
       first_value(city) OVER w AS city, 
       first_value(request_id) OVER w AS request_id
FROM "Records"
JOIN highest ON "Records".request_id < highest.id -- exclude the highest request_id
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY (firm, name) ORDER BY request_id DESC
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
```

And then you tie it all together with sub-queries (and removing columns with duplicate information):

```
WITH highest AS (
    SELECT request_id AS id
    FROM "01_System_Log"
    ORDER BY request_date DESC LIMIT 1
)
SELECT curr.firm, curr.name, 
       prev.city AS previous_city, prev.request_id AS previous_request_id,
       curr.city AS current_city, curr.request_id AS current_request_id
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT firm, name, 
           first_value(city) OVER w AS city, 
           first_value(request_id) OVER w AS request_id
    FROM "Records"
    JOIN highest ON "Records".request_id < highest.id
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY (firm, name) ORDER BY request_id DESC
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) ) prev
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT firm, name, city, request_id
    FROM "Records"
    JOIN highest ON "Records".request_id = highest.id ) curr USING (firm, name)
ORDER BY curr.firm;
```